# method to print a Credit Card Table

Tags: ruby, methods

Can someone explain to me how works this method, I know it print a table and works well but I don't understand how it works :(
help!

```
class CreditCard
  attr_reader :name, :number, :expiration, :cvc
  attr_accessor :status

    def initialize(name,number,expiration,cvc,status)
      @name = name 
      @number = number
      @expiration = expiration
      @cvc = cvc
      @status = status
    end

    def information
      card_information = "#{@name}", "#{@number}", "#{@expiration}", "#{@cvc}", "#{@status}"  
    end  

end

card_array = []
credit_card.each do |x|
  card_array << x.information
end
```

## THIS METHOD!!!

```
print "Name".center(20)," Number".center(25)," Expiration".center(20)," Cvc".center(22)," Status".center(25),"\n"
puts "___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________"
card_array.each do |x|
  x.each do |card|
    print "|",card.center(20),"|"
  end
   print "\n"
end
print "\n"
```

Comment: This method https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-center ?

Comment: yes, I wonder if there's another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what part specifically is confusing, so apologies if this comes across as a little condescending. Let's step through this line by line:

```
print "Name".center(20)," Number".center(25)," Expiration".center(20)," Cvc".center(22)," Status".center(25),"\n"
```

this first line calls [print](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-print) passing it a variable number of string arguments to print out, one after another. These string arguments are all be [center](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-center)ed as column headers. After all the headers are output, a line break is printed beginning a new line in the output.

```
puts "___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________"
```

This line is just for formatting, outputting a divider between the table header and contents. Since they use [puts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) instead of print here, a new line is automatically output after the string.

```
card_array.each do |x|
...
end
```

This block is a for each construct, so for each credit card in the `card_array` we will assign the card to the local variable `x` and then execute the code inside this block.

```
 x.each do |card|
 ...
 end
```

Again, this is a foreach construct where `x` is the credit card as an array of strings (see the `information` method). We assign each string, one at a time to `card` and then execute the block within.

```
print "|",card.center(20),"|"
```

Here's another print call, where we use the variable length arguments to pass 3 parameters, the current string in `card` and what I assume to be table cell borders.

```
print "\n"
```

Then we just have 2 more calls to print, at the end of each of the blocks, printing out new lines so that each credit card is on it's own row.

Having explained the block in question, I feel a source of confusion for this code possibly comes from the `information` method, where, it might not be immediately obvious that

```
card_information = "#{@name}", "#{@number}", "#{@expiration}", "#{@cvc}", "#{@status}"
```

is actually creating an array of strings that are then being added to the `card_array` so `card_array` is an array of arrays that would end up looking something like

```
[ ["card holder name", "card number", ...], ["second card hold name", "second card number", ...], ...]
```

It took me a second reading to catch that they were doing that, so figure this might be what got skipped over to make the block in question unclear (if you were thinking it was an array of `CreditCard` objects instead of an array of strings.)